# Using Regex for words between quotation marks and also asterix's in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to colour words depending on where they are. I have got quotation marks working by using public `Regex Invertedcommas = new Regex("\".*\"");` however, I don't understand the structure of it. How would I rewrite this but for using *'s?

I've been searching around but many people create their Regex's using var, which isn't the same structure as mine.

Short question but researching hasn't helped me - thanks in advance

I am creating a rich text box that acts like visual studio with regards to colour syntax, so anything in "" will be dark red, anything after // will be green as it's a comment. So the regex above displays everything in quotation marks to be dark red, I'm wondering how I can adapt that regex so that anything within -> *this text here* is a different colour.

The colouring isn't the issue it's just setting up the regex

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to match?

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: The structure of the regex is simply as follows: `\"` is an escaped quotation mark. This tells regex to literally look for a quotation mark. So, to do this for `*`s, you'd just escape those characters. Assuming you have text like *some text* and you want to find "some text", you'd do `Regex Invertedstars = new Regex("\*.*\*");`. The first and third `*` will be interpreted literally and the second `*` will be interpreted as a regex metacharacter.

Comment: Perfect ill give it a shot now - thankyou brittenb

Comment: Unfortunately i get unrecognised escape sequence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex("\"(?<InsideQuote>[^\"]+)\"|//(?<Comment>[^\r\n]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

[image: Test the regex]